# Instantiate WebComponent "easily"

Tags: javascript, web-component

I have created a **simple Web Component** to add in a parent (say "div#left" in this example). The component do nothing, except showing a text (it will be more elaborate later).

It's working if I do:
in html

```
<my-comp text="TEST"></my-comp>
```

in JS

```
document.getElementById("left").innerHTML += '<my-comp text="bar"></my-comp>';
```

or

```
var c = document.createElement("my-comp");
c.setAttribute("text", "buzz");
document.getElementById("left").appendChild(c);
```

But, I want something more "easy" to instantiate it (more "natural" for me...), via a method like

```
const gb = new MyComp({ text: "foo" });
gb.addInParent("#left")
```

or via a generic function (to instantiate any component), like:

```
const gb = new MyComp({ text: "foo" });
addInParent("#left", gb)
```

It may be simple, but I can't find how to implement the method/function addInParent... (all my research leads me to React or equivalent, which I don't use for this specific case)

Thank's in advance

Comment: `function addInParent(sel, el) { document.querySelector(sel).appendChild(el); }`?

Comment: So simple ...
(I had tested at some point, but my component had a small bug; I went in the wrong direction ...)
Thank you very much !

Comment: And do use ``append`` when you don't use the ``appendChild`` **return** value. ``append`` is twice as fast: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/7889/0/append-vs-appendchild-createtextnode#latest_results_block

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i got it right but you only want to change de inner part of the component to the received prop, right?

Have you tried slots?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots

for example in your web component render method

```
<div>
    <slot>Slotted text</slot>
</div>
```

and then in your page you call your component and pass the text like

```
<my-comp>My text here</my-comp>
```

Comment: Hi
No, the component is more complex, it was simplified for the question... appendChild / append is the answer